# What rules govern the usage of "tout" to mean "very"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, usage

I sometimes see *tout* used where I might expect *très*, such as in this sentence:

> On vient d'un tout petit village dans les Ardennes.

Is there a limited set of words for which it is normal to use *tout* rather than *très*?

Comment: Indeed, for instance, you can't use it with "grand"... But I can't find the reason it works with some, and not with others...

Comment: We can use "Il est devenu tout grand cet arbre" to emphasize that the tree has become very big.

Comment: I rather agree with random: "tout grand" is indeed never used. One would always say "il est devenu très grand".

Comment: We are not just talking about what the preferred expression is, but also about the different possibilities, and "tout grand" is in fact an expression that is used in French. Other examples include "ouvrir tout grand les yeux", "un tout grand merci" and more. It is just a different register, that is used mostly in literature. Here's the ngram to support it. http://tinyurl.com/glhsgz9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific rule defining the use of "tout" instead of "très".
It is mostly an oral use adding an undertone.
For example, "un très petit bébé" in a french's mouth means that an usually small baby. "un tout petit bébé" means a cute baby.
Sometimes the undertone is friendship, cuteness, humour ...
If you use "très" to mean "very" in some cases, your friend might not react as expected.

Keep in mind : "tout + adj" does not mean "très" in every cases.
"La salle est toute bleue" : means the (almost) only color of the room is blue.

Comment: What do you mean by "If you use "très" to mean "very" in some cases, your friend might not react as expected." ?

Comment: "tout" is laudatory while "très" is more pejorative

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is possible to use it with almost any adjective (tout petit, tout beau, etc...) but in my mind using it implies some sort of affection, and denotes a sense of endearment towards the thing being described.

A bit like using 'wee' in English: un tout petit bébé -> a wee baby

I do not think there is an actual rule for it.